# Audio in XCode 5 does not play

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, ios-simulator

I am relatively new to coding, and I was trying to make my own game in XCode.  I do not have a developer's license yet, so I don't think I can put the game on my phone to try it out.  I found several different ways to play sounds, and I wanted to put a 30 second song I made in garageband in the background to see how it works.  I tried it with a .mp3 file, but that did not work.  I found more resources on how to put a .wav file in, so I converted it and tried with that.  I followed several different tutorials and instructions exactly, but none of them worked.  Finally I ended up doing it like this and trying to run it, but it did not play in the simulator.  I have tried unchecking and checking the Play User Interface Sound Effects button in System Preferences like people said, but it did not work.  I used AudioToolbox framework.  Here is my code for the music:
.h

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
SystemSoundID BackgroundMusicID;
```

.m (I did not #import anything into the .m, but I tried it)  The file name for the music is "BackgroundMusic.wav" exactly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *BackgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BackgroundMusic" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)BackgroundMusicURL, &BackgroundMusicID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(BackgroundMusicID);
}
```

Thank you for any help!  If you have any ideas as to why it won't play, or if it is just a problem with the simulator (I saw other people saying that, but none of their fixes worked unless I did something wrong).  I would like the song to play as soon as the game loads up, but I have tried putting AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(BackgroundMusicID); under a button and under touchesbegan.  Again, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just curious, does it play if you call a method which plays the sound a second or 2 after the view is loaded? You can try like this: `[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];`

Comment: @troop231 I tried it and the music still did not play.  I made a method called PlayMusic, then I kept the NSURL lines and added [self performSelector:@selector(PlayMusic) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]; in ViewDidLoad, and in the method definition of PlayMusic I put AudioServicesPlaySystemSound.  Does that sound right to you?  Do you have any other ideas about what it could be?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. But try the following:

```
NSString *BackgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BackgroundMusic" ofType:@"wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:BackgroundMusicURL], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(BackgroundMusicID);
```

Another thing is:

Don't try creating a clip that is exactly 30 seconds in length, instead try it first with 25-second or a 28-second clip.

And if that still does't work, please provide more code specifically where your dispose your sound and if you ave animation code, please post those as well.

Comment: Thank you, I did.  I just wasn't sure which one did it.  I guess it was probably yours.  Is there anyway I can say they both helped?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `NSURL` to use: `URLForResource: withExtension:` instead of `fileURLWithPath`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *BackgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BackgroundMusic"
                                                withExtension:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)BackgroundMusicURL, &BackgroundMusicID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(BackgroundMusicID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I used that type of code and shortened it to 25 seconds like @Unheilig said and it worked perfectly.